# I'm trying to copy worksheets from one workbook to another

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm trying to copy several complete worksheets from one workbook to another.  I have recorded a macro to create the code, but when I implement it into my main workbook I get the `Subscript Out of Range error (runtime error ‘9’)`.  My research for this question reveals how to copy data from one workbook to another, but not multiple worksheets.
Here is the code.  It is supposed to copy the worksheets in Therm Cal Compiler.xlsm and paste them into SN1813016 - Copy.xlsx after the fourth sheet:

```
Windows("Therm Cal Compiler.xlsm").Activate
Sheets(Array("Thermal Calibration", "Therm_R1_-_0uA_-25C", "Therm_R1_-_0uA_0C", _
    "Therm_R1_-_0uA_23C", "Therm_R1_-_0uA_40C", "Therm_R1_-_0uA_50C", _
    "Therm_R1_-_0uA_60C", "Therm_R1_-_0uA_65C", "Therm_R1_-_0uA_70C")).Select
Sheets(Array("Thermal Calibration", "Therm_R1_-_0uA_-25C", "Therm_R1_-_0uA_0C", _
    "Therm_R1_-_0uA_23C", "Therm_R1_-_0uA_40C", "Therm_R1_-_0uA_50C", _
    "Therm_R1_-_0uA_60C", "Therm_R1_-_0uA_65C", "Therm_R1_-_0uA_70C")).Copy Before _
    :=Workbooks("SN1813016 - Copy.xlsx").Sheets(5)
```

Both the `Therm Cal Compiler.xlsm` and `SN1813016 - Copy.xlsx` are open, and the error occurs on the second array command,

```
Sheets(Array("Thermal Calibration",…)).Copy Before _
    :=Workbooks("SN1813016 - Copy.xlsx").Sheets(5).
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your destination workbook does not have 5 sheets, this will cause that error.

You should use `After:=` instead.  Also, the `Activate` and `Select`s are not required.

Try this

```
Workbooks("Therm Cal Compiler.xlsm").Worksheets(Array( _
  "Thermal Calibration", _
  "Therm_R1_-_0uA_-25C", _
  "Therm_R1_-_0uA_0C", _
  "Therm_R1_-_0uA_23C", _
  "Therm_R1_-_0uA_40C", _
  "Therm_R1_-_0uA_50C", _
  "Therm_R1_-_0uA_60C", _
  "Therm_R1_-_0uA_65C", _
  "Therm_R1_-_0uA_70C")).Copy _
  After:=Workbooks("SN1813016 - Copy.xlsx").Sheets(4)
```